# getting data from datagridview and adding itto another table

Tags: vb.net

im doing a software do handle a library, book stock, readers getting books and whatnot... in the form where im suppose to register a book loan, i keep getting an error saying System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=O operador '&' não está definido para cadeia "insert into Levantamento values(" e tipo 'DataRowView'.(the operator & is not defined for the string..... and then it says its type data row view

this is the code that gets the data from the datagrid view into a textbox

```
 Dim s As String = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
    'command to bring data where itemid matches with the selected cell row itemid
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Livro.ID_livro, Livro.Titulo, Autor.Autor, [Tipo de livro].tipodelivro, Livro.[data de ediçao], Livro.Quantidade FROM Livro INNER JOIN Autor ON Livro.ID_autor = Autor.ID_autor INNER JOIN [Tipo de livro] ON Livro.ID_tipodelivro = [Tipo de livro].ID_tipodelivro WHERE Livro.ID_livro =" + s + "", con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds)
    TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Titulo").ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Quantidade").ToString()
```

and this is the code i use to insert data into the intented database, it first inserts all the fields(2 of them are dates but are varchar in database, the thing is... some of the fields of the intended table are IDs... but visually i see text... mayb thats it?

```
  Dim sql As String = "insert into Levantamento values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "')"
        Dim sqlcom As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader()
        Dim temp2 As Double = TextBox2.Text
        Dim temp3 As Double = temp2 - temp3
        TextBox3.Text += temp3
        Dim sqlstr4 As String = "update livro set Quantidade='" & TextBox3.Text & "' where Titulo = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        comando = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstr4, con)
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code.  You should start by setting Option Strict On and that will catch some of them at compile time.  You should also stop using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code and start doing it the proper way and use parameters.  Read here for why and how: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: i still cant understand how i that link can solve my problem... it shows another way of inserting into database... but my problem stays the same... where is the error in the code... annd why does it occur?

Comment: That link probably won't solve your problem, which is why I put it in a comment and not an answer.  I provided an answer below, in the answer section, that should hopefully solve your problem.  That's how this site works: if information answers the question asked then it should be provided as an answer while other information and requests for more information or clarification should be provided as comments. People don't always do the right thing and sometimes there's a grey area but that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: its solved... ty, i had a character wrong in the combo box value member and i didnt saw... ty for ur time

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the issue is with `ComboBox1.SelectedValue`.  Have you bound a `DataTable` to that `ComboBox` but not set the `ValueMember`?